# find min no of coins required to get a value i: dynamic programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

Find out the  number of coins required to compute an amount of money, such that a least amount of coins are needed. coins are of value 1,3 and 5.
whats wrong with this code ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     int i,j,sum,coins[]={1,3,5}, min[sum];
     cin>>sum;
     for(i=0;i<=sum;i++)
        min[i]=999;
     min[0]=0;
     for(i=1;i<=sum;i++)
     {
       for(j=0;j<3;j++)
       {
            if((coins[j]<=i) && ( (min[i-coins[ j ]]    + 1)    < min[i] ))
            {

                    min[i]=min[i-coins[j]] +1;
                    cout<<i<<"="<<min[i];cout<<endl;    
            }
       }
     }
     cout<<min[sum];    
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: what output are you looking for, and what happens? Your code doesn't seem to make much sense for this simple problem. Why do you need an array of size `sum`?

Comment: It lacks comments.  Other than that, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the size of the array `min`, which is `sum`, before initialising it.

It should be after `cin >> sum`.

As an advice, it is always better to declare and initialise arrays separately.